# How to select region outgoing traffic in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Is it possible to select where the network traffic will outgoing in google colab files?

Most traffic leaves through the US, some datasets are blocked for certain countries.

Is it possible to select or route where it will be outgoing? As the list IP ranges.

https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json

The most of the IP I get are from the range 35.185.0.0/17